# General solution of a differential equation: $(x+1)\frac{d^2 u}{d x^2} + x \frac{d u}{d x}-u=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question asks for the general solution of the following differential equation:

$$(x+1)\frac{d^2 u}{d x^2} + x \frac{d u}{d x}-u=0$$

I wonder, in general, how can this type of differentials be solved? By finding an integrating factor?

Comment: two solutions are $x$ and $e^{-x}$

Comment: after the hint you will get $$u(x)=C_1x+C_2e^{-x}$$

Comment: why exactly are all solutions of this form?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner what hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation is a linear homogeneous equation of order $2$. The theory of that class of equations tells us that there are two linearly independent solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$ such that the general solution is $u(x)=C_1\,u_1(x)+C_2\,u_2(x)$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary constants. The problem is reduced to find $u_1$ and $u_2$. Unfortunately there is no general method for this. But if somehow you happen to know one solution $u_1$, you can find a second one of the form $v(x)\,u_1(x)$. This is known as the [method of reduction of order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order). The problem is reduced now to find one solution. ¿How to do this? Again, there is no general method. But sometimes one is able to guess a solution, looking for solutions of a particular form: polynomial, exponential,...

For the equation in the question, it seems reasonable to look for a polynomial solution, and then we find that $u(x)=x$ is a solution.

Comment: Thank you! Just for the record, in general if the order of equation is $n$, it would be enough to find $n$ solutions, right?

Comment: Yes, an homogeneous linear equation of order $n$ has $n$ linearly independent solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any general method, however I did figure out a method for your specific ODE based on substitution:

---

Start by substituting $u=vx$. After applying the product rule twice should give:
$$\frac{du}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx} \text{ and } \frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}=x\frac{d^2 v}{dx^2}+2\frac{dv}{dx}$$
After the substitution, you should have:
$$x(x+1)\frac{d^2 v}{dx^2}+(x^2+2x+2)\frac{dv}{dx}=0$$
Notice this now becomes easy to solve, since we can easily reduce the order of the ODE to first order by substituting $z=\frac{dv}{dx}$. This will give a separable ODE, which is significantly easier to solve than the second order ODE you had:
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=-\frac{x^2+2x+2}{x(x+1)}\cdot z \tag{1}$$

---

Solving this ODE for $z(x)$ is easy by applying polynomial division and partial fractions:
$$\frac{x^2+2x+2}{x(x+1)}\stackrel{\text{poly div}}=1+\frac{x+2}{x(x+1)}\stackrel{\text{partial frac}}{=}1+\frac{2}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}$$
Applying this on $(1)$ gives:
$$\int \frac{1}{z}~dz=\int \left(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{2}{x}-1\right)~dx$$

Doing the integration, and reapplying all the substitutions should give you the same general solution @Dr.SonnhardGraubner suggested for $u(x)$.